# Android legacy launcher icon dimensions and padding

Tags: android, android-studio, android-icons

I am looking for the Android specification for legacy launcher icons.

I found the specification for Android adaptive icons, which is 108x108, with content inside a 72x72 for mdpi: https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/ui_guidelines/icon_design_adaptive

I also found the specification for Android Play Store icon, which is 512x512, with content inside 384x384 (75%). https://developer.android.com/google-play/resources/icon-design-specifications

However, I cannot seem to find the specification for legacy launcher icons. i.e. The main thing I'm looking for is:

- Size of the padding
- Radius size
- Shadow properties

According to this:
https://iconhandbook.co.uk/reference/chart/android/
the mdpi size is 48x48, but no mention of padding, corner radius, shadow etc.

Answer (score 0):

If you're in Android Studio, and you do "Image Asset" in the Resource Manager's add (+) menu, you can take the 512x512 icon and it will generate the others for you, including a legacy version - there are a few options like Round, Square, and some weird long ones.

Just eyeballing it, they look identical to the standard Round Icon and Square Icon previews for the adaptive icons that get generated, I think they're just literally taking either of those and making a "legacy" copy.

Sorry that's not very concrete - if it helps the generated icon **is** 48px by 48px for mdpi! And there's more info about the actual design specs here:
https://material.io/design/iconography/product-icons.html#grid-and-keyline-shapes
I know, this info is all over the place and it's really hard to find everything you need. But personally, designing for those adaptive specs and just letting the Resource Manager handle generating the icon worked well for me, I'd use that if you can